# Unity3D iOS device token is always null

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I am trying to get push notifications to work on iOS, but I can not get access to the device token!

My Unity version is 5.4.1f1.

I have enabled the Push Notifications capability in XCode and all the certificates are setup correctly:
[image]

In my script in the start method I call this:

```
UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications
    (UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationType.Alert | UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationType.Badge
    | UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationType.Sound, true);
```

Then from the update method I call this method:

```
private bool RegisterTokenWithPlayfab( System.Action successCallback,
    System.Action<PlayFabError> errorCallback )
{
    byte[] token = UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.deviceToken;
    if(token != null)
    {
        // Registration on backend
    }
    else
    {
        string errorDescription = UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.registrationError;
        Debug.Log( "Push Notifications Registration failed with: " + errorDescription );
        return false;
    }
}
```

The token keeps being empty, so the else-branch is entered every call. Also, the registrationError keeps being empty.

Can someone point me in the right direction on this? What else can I try or how can I get more infos on what is going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`Go to your application target. Choose Capabilities and ensure that ‘Push Notifications’ is enabled there.`

Comment: I use Unity version 5.4.1f1.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check deviceToken in a Coroutine or Update.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Networking;
    using System.Collections;
    using NotificationServices = UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices;
    using NotificationType = UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationType;

    public class NotificationRegistrationExample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        bool tokenSent;

        void Start()
        {
            tokenSent = false;

            NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications(
                NotificationType.Alert |
                NotificationType.Badge |
                NotificationType.Sound, true);
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if (!tokenSent)
            {
                byte[] token = NotificationServices.deviceToken;
                if (token != null)
                {
                    // send token to a provider
                    string token = System.BitConverter.ToString(token).Replace('-', '%');
                    Debug.Log(token)
                    tokenSent = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The implementation is horrible, but we don't have callbacks from Unity side so we need to keep listening that variable value.

Check the documentation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications.html

**Also seems to need internet**. I guess there is an Apple service going on there.

Yes, registration error is empty even when user deniy permissions.

What i did is to use UniRX and set an Observable fron a Coroutine with a time out so it dont keep forever asking for it.
 If you accepted and you do not received the token might be the internet conection. And i guess you are teying this on a real device.